# MySQL UNION Only Includes First Table

Tags: mysql, left-join, union, right-join

I need to perform a FULL OUTER JOIN on two tables and I'm trying to implement it in MySQL using the LEFT JOIN/RIGHT JOIN/UNION ALL technique.

Here are the original tables:

```
giving_totals:
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| country_iso2 | total_given   | supersector |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| AE           | 1396986989.02 |           3 |
| AE           |  596757809.20 |           4 |
| AE           |  551810209.87 |           5 |
| AE           |   25898255.77 |           7 |
| AE           |      32817.63 |           9 |
...
+--------------+---------------+-------------+

receiving_totals:
 +--------------+----------------+-------------+
| country_iso2 | total_received | supersector |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| AE           |    34759000.00 |           3 |
| AE           |      148793.82 |           7 |
| AE           |         734.30 |           9 |
| AF           |  6594479965.85 |           1 |
| AF           |  2559712971.26 |           2 |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I want the resulting table to have one entry for each country for each supersector code even if it did not give or receive money for that sector (this is from the AidData project dataset in case anyone is familiar.) I thought to accomplish this by doing a UNION of a LEFT JOIN (to get all giving entries) and RIGHT JOIN (to get all receiving entries.) Here's the query I tried:

```
SELECT g.country_iso2 AS country_iso2, g.total_given AS `total_given`,R.total_received AS `total_received`,g.supersector AS `supersector` 
FROM (`giving_totals` `g` 
LEFT JOIN `receiving_totals` `r` 
ON(((g.country_iso2 = r.country_iso2) 
AND (g.supersector = r.supersector)))) 

UNION ALL

SELECT g.country_iso2 AS country_iso2, g.total_given AS `total_given`,R.total_received    AS `total_received`,g.supersector AS `supersector` 
FROM (`giving_totals` `g` 
RIGHT JOIN `receiving_totals` `r` 
ON(((g.country_iso2 = r.country_iso2) 
AND (g.supersector = r.supersector))))
```

But this only returns the first join, whether or not I put the right or left join first. I think I may be misunderstanding the UNION operation because the individual joins each return what I expected. Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Use table aliases from the table you join to in the second select of your union, otherwise you get NULL country_iso2 and supersector. Use UNION instead of UNION ALL if you don't want to see rows with both given and received twice. Apart from that there is nothing wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method to do a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT driver.country_iso2 AS country_iso2,
       g.total_given AS `total_given`,
       R.total_received AS `total_received`,
       driver.supersector AS `supersector` 
from ((select distinct country_iso2, supersector
       from giving_totals
      ) union
      (select distinct country_iso2, supersector
       from receiving_totals
      )
     ) driver left outer join
     giving_totals gt
     on gt.country_iso2 = driver.country_iso2 and
        gt.supersector = driver.country_iso2 left outer join
     receiving_totals rt
     on rt.country_iso2 = driver.country_iso2 and
        rt.supersector = driver.country_iso2
```

That is, do the union as a subquery to get all the combinations you are interested in.  Then you can do a `left outer join` to that table.

The reason for your problem is that aliases in the second query.  You can try this instead:

```
SELECT r.country_iso2 AS country_iso2, g.total_given AS `total_given`,R.total_received    AS `total_received`,r.supersector AS `supersector` 
FROM (`giving_totals` `g` 
RIGHT JOIN `receiving_totals` `r` 
ON(((g.country_iso2 = r.country_iso2) 
AND (g.supersector = r.supersector))))
```

The original form would have NULLs for these values.

Comment: Using your first query, the total_given and total_received fields are NULL (which I see now you mentioned at the bottom of the post.) But how do I use the second query to get the actual values? Running that query by itself had the same effect as my original query.

Comment: @Matt . . . You are getting NULL values when there are mismatches.  Some values of iso/supersector exist in only one table.  The value in the other table will be NULL.

Comment: I'm still trying to work this out but I don't understand why the UNION I tried doesn't work. Together, the LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN have all possible combinations so bringing them into one table should have them all together. But the UNION wasn't working as it should have. Maybe I'm not understanding your comments but I still don't understand why my original query won't work.

Comment: @Matt . . . Did you see my revised version with the `join`?  You are doing a right join, so when you choose `g.country_iso2` it may be NULL.  You just have to use the right alias, `r`, instead of `g`, in the second subquery.